# Will ubuntu supports switchable graphics?

Tags: 14.04

does ubuntu supports switchable graphics? I am using HP Pavilion dv6 laptop. I tried ubuntu 12.04 but my laptop is becoming too hot.

Answer (score 0):

Some graphics switching is available depending upon the type of graphics your HP has - nvidia-prime and bumblebee are often mentioned in posts here for that purpose.

I have a DV7 that I run for my kid, and it's a real space warmer.  I would not be able to run the computer at all without tlp, available on the Ubuntu software center or the tlp website at [linrunner.de/tlp](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html)

As far as graphics are concerned, my DV7 would not recognize the graphics card properly with early releases of Ubuntu 14.04, and the proprietary drivers would not work properly either - HP may have some BIOS specific to them which is not well recognized.  What worked on that computer were the oibaf graphics drivers available at [launchpad.net/~oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers)

The combination of tlp and more advanced drivers has at least kept my dv7 operable, although temperatures are regularly over 60 Celcius while idle.